# Splitting Excel File Using VB

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel worksheet that produces data into another worksheet. After this I export from the worksheet into a csv format. I need to be able to split the data every 250 rows into a new file regardless of the information contained. I'm using VB for the coding in this.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please post some code you have tried first.

Answer (score 0):

If your spreadsheet is XLSX Office 2007, you can look at the [Open XML Format SDK](http://cdonner.com/introduction-to-microsofts-open-xml-format-sdk-20-with-a-focus-on-excel-documents.htm).